# Use 'LIKE %word%' for ACF Query Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF plugin on my wordpress site and I want to code custom research.
I have many products and I want to display products which contain the searched word.

I do my query like this :

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'meta_key'      => 'brand',
            'meta_value'        => $word,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE');



$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But this display only products with the brand which exactly matches with $word.
for exemple if I search "yan" I want to display products with the brand "YANMAR", "POLYAN", "TRYANPO", etc.

How to do this please ?

Thank you and have a good day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'brand',
        'value' => $word,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```